# <sec:authorize generate Invalid path error with Facelets template

Tags: jsf, spring-security, facelets

I am trying to use spring security with Facelets.
When I use sec:authorize in my page I have this error:

```
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml"> Invalid path :/template.xhtml
```

and everything works fine if I remove `<sec:authorize`

here is my Facelets file:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" template="/template.xhtml"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">

<ui:define name="title">
   HOME  
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="form">
    <p:panelGrid id="homeGrd" columns="4" >
        <f:facet name="header">  
             List of Accounts
            </f:facet>
        <sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="padding: 0 0 3px 0;">
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it 
I used :

```
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ADMIN">
```

instead of

```
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
```